# Parse into JSON using Spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have retrieved a table from SQL Server which contains over 3 million records.

Top 10 Records:

```
+---------+-------------+----------+
|ACCOUNTNO|VEHICLENUMBER|CUSTOMERID|
+---------+-------------+----------+
| 10003014|    MH43AJ411|  20000000|
| 10003014|    MH43AJ411|  20000001|
| 10003015|   MH12GZ3392|  20000002|
| 10003016|    GJ15Z8173|  20000003|
| 10003018|    MH05AM902|  20000004|
| 10003019|   GJ15CD7657|  20001866|
| 10003019|   MH02BY7774|  20000005|
| 10003019|   MH02DG7774|  20000933|
| 10003019|   GJ15CA7387|  20001865|
| 10003019|   GJ15CB9601|  20001557|
+---------+-------------+----------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

Here `ACCOUNTNO` is unique, same `ACCOUNTNO` might have more than one `VEHICLENUMBER`, for each Vehicle we might have unique `CUSTOMERID` with respect to that `VEHICLENUMBER`

I want to export as a JSON format.

**This is my code to achieve the output:**

```
package com.issuer.pack2.spark
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql._
object sqltojson {
  
  def main(args:Array[String])
    {
      System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:/winutil/")
      val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SQLtoJSON").setMaster("local[*]")
      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
      val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
      import sqlContext.implicits._
      
      val jdbcSqlConnStr = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.70.88;databaseName=ISSUER;user=bhaskar;password=welcome123;"
      
      val jdbcDbTable = "[HISTORY].[TP_CUSTOMER_PREPAIDACCOUNTS]"
      val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map("url" -> jdbcSqlConnStr,"dbtable" -> jdbcDbTable)).load()
    //  jdbcDF.show(10)
      jdbcDF.registerTempTable("tp_customer_account")
      val res01 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT ACCOUNTNO, VEHICLENUMBER, CUSTOMERID FROM tp_customer_account GROUP BY ACCOUNTNO, VEHICLENUMBER, CUSTOMERID ORDER BY ACCOUNTNO ")
      
  // res01.show(10)
     res01.coalesce(1).write.json("D:/res01.json")    
      
    }
}
```

**The output I got:**

```
{"ACCOUNTNO":10003014,"VEHICLENUMBER":"MH43AJ411","CUSTOMERID":20000001}
{"ACCOUNTNO":10003014,"VEHICLENUMBER":"MH43AJ411","CUSTOMERID":20000000}
{"ACCOUNTNO":10003015,"VEHICLENUMBER":"MH12GZ3392","CUSTOMERID":20000002}
{"ACCOUNTNO":10003016,"VEHICLENUMBER":"GJ15Z8173","CUSTOMERID":20000003}
{"ACCOUNTNO":10003018,"VEHICLENUMBER":"MH05AM902","CUSTOMERID":20000004}
{"ACCOUNTNO":10003019,"VEHICLENUMBER":"MH02BY7774","CUSTOMERID":20000005}
{"ACCOUNTNO":10003019,"VEHICLENUMBER":"GJ15CA7387","CUSTOMERID":20001865}
{"ACCOUNTNO":10003019,"VEHICLENUMBER":"GJ15CD7657","CUSTOMERID":20001866}
{"ACCOUNTNO":10003019,"VEHICLENUMBER":"MH02DG7774","CUSTOMERID":20000933}
{"ACCOUNTNO":10003019,"VEHICLENUMBER":"GJ15CB9601","CUSTOMERID":20001557}
{"ACCOUNTNO":10003019,"VEHICLENUMBER":"GJ15CD7387","CUSTOMERID":20029961}
{"ACCOUNTNO":10003019,"VEHICLENUMBER":"GJ15CF7747","CUSTOMERID":20009020}
{"ACCOUNTNO":10003019,"VEHICLENUMBER":"GJ15CB727","CUSTOMERID":20000008}
{"ACCOUNTNO":10003019,"VEHICLENUMBER":"GJ15CA7837","CUSTOMERID":20001223}
{"ACCOUNTNO":10003019,"VEHICLENUMBER":"GJ15CD7477","CUSTOMERID":20001690}
{"ACCOUNTNO":10003020,"VEHICLENUMBER":"MH01AX5658","CUSTOMERID":20000006}
{"ACCOUNTNO":10003021,"VEHICLENUMBER":"GJ15AD727","CUSTOMERID":20000007}
{"ACCOUNTNO":10003023,"VEHICLENUMBER":"GU15PP7567","CUSTOMERID":20000009}
{"ACCOUNTNO":10003024,"VEHICLENUMBER":"GJ15CA7567","CUSTOMERID":20000010}
{"ACCOUNTNO":10003025,"VEHICLENUMBER":"GJ5JB9312","CUSTOMERID":20000011}
```

But I want to get the JSON format output like this:
I have written the JSON below manually (maybe I have designed wrongly, I want that the `ACCOUNTNO` should be unique) for first three records of my above table.

```
{
    "ACCOUNTNO":10003014,
    "VEHICLE": [
        { "VEHICLENUMBER":"MH43AJ411", "CUSTOMERID":20000000},
        { "VEHICLENUMBER":"MH43AJ411", "CUSTOMERID":20000001}
    ],
    "ACCOUNTNO":10003015,
    "VEHICLE": [
        { "VEHICLENUMBER":"MH12GZ3392", "CUSTOMERID":20000002}
    ]
}
```

So, how to achieve this JSON format using Spark code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Scala spark-sql

You can do the following (instead of `registerTempTable` you can use`createOrReplaceTempView` as `registerTempTable` is deprecated)

```
jdbcDF.createGlobalTempView("tp_customer_account")
val res01 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT ACCOUNTNO, collect_list(struct(`VEHICLENUMBER`, `CUSTOMERID`)) as VEHICLE FROM tp_customer_account GROUP BY ACCOUNTNO ORDER BY ACCOUNTNO ")

res01.coalesce(1).write.json("D:/res01.json")
```

You should get your desired output as

```
{"ACCOUNTNO":"10003014","VEHICLE":[{"VEHICLENUMBER":"MH43AJ411","CUSTOMERID":"20000000"},{"VEHICLENUMBER":"MH43AJ411","CUSTOMERID":"20000001"}]}
{"ACCOUNTNO":"10003015","VEHICLE":[{"VEHICLENUMBER":"MH12GZ3392","CUSTOMERID":"20000002"}]}
{"ACCOUNTNO":"10003016","VEHICLE":[{"VEHICLENUMBER":"GJ15Z8173","CUSTOMERID":"20000003"}]}
{"ACCOUNTNO":"10003018","VEHICLE":[{"VEHICLENUMBER":"MH05AM902","CUSTOMERID":"20000004"}]}
{"ACCOUNTNO":"10003019","VEHICLE":[{"VEHICLENUMBER":"GJ15CD7657","CUSTOMERID":"20001866"},{"VEHICLENUMBER":"MH02BY7774","CUSTOMERID":"20000005"},{"VEHICLENUMBER":"MH02DG7774","CUSTOMERID":"20000933"},{"VEHICLENUMBER":"GJ15CA7387","CUSTOMERID":"20001865"},{"VEHICLENUMBER":"GJ15CB9601","CUSTOMERID":"20001557"}]}
```

## Scala spark API

Using *spark scala API*, you can do the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val res01 = jdbcDF.groupBy("ACCOUNTNO")
    .agg(collect_list(struct("VEHICLENUMBER", "CUSTOMERID")).as("VEHICLE"))

res01.coalesce(1).write.json("D:/res01.json")
```

You should be getting the same answer as the sql way.

I hope the answer is helpful.

Comment: What are the Scala API s, functions are available? I want to learn and practice  these various API and functions, give me an important list of Scala API to work with XML, JSON etc semi structured data

Comment: here are some links [scala spark functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html), and  [spark xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) and [spark json and more](https://szczeles.github.io/Reading-JSON-CSV-and-XML-files-efficiently-in-Apache-Spark/) just search the web and you will find abundant infos :) and of course you need a lot of practice

Comment: You can help me by giving some links too. Do you have any use cases using these `collect_list`, `struct`

Comment: collect_list and struct are inbuilt functions of spark. you can check the scala spark functions link in my above comment

Comment: When I am running the spark-sql query you have given, it is throwing error in eclipse: 
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: tp_customer_account; line 1 pos 86

Comment: I guess you are using older version of spark so just use registerTempTable then

Comment: registerTempTable has worked but I am not getting the proper result as you have shown in your output.  I am getting same element multiple times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176142/discussion-between-bhaskar-das-and-ramesh-maharjan).